# How to create a directory in downloads folder with swift on macos? Permission exception.

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, permissions

I am struggling to simply create a folder in the users download directory on macos with this code:

```
static func createFolderInDownloadsDirectory() {
    let downloadsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let downloadsDirectoryWithFolder = downloadsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("FolderToCreate")

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: downloadsDirectoryWithFolder, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
You don’t have permission to save the file “FolderToCreate” in the folder “Downloads”.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Xcode 9 and later enables sandboxing by default, which severely limits interactions with the system. However you can still write to the Downloads folder by adding an entitlement to your app:

Select your target, then **Capabilities** and set Downloads Folder to Read/Write:

[image: Enable read/write to Downloads Folder under App Sandbox]

If you have no intention of distributing your app through the Mac App Store, you can turn off sandboxing. Your application can still be signed but users will get a warning when they first launch your app.

Comment: In my case I had trouble with another directory, so `User Selected File` did it for me. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Xcode Version 15.2 (15C500b)

set App Sandbox at Target->Your Project->Sign & Capabilities->App Sandbox