# How would I check for a file in a specified directory in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, macos, swift5, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to verify that a file is present in the Downloads folder of the user. I have already enabled access to the Downloads folder in the permissions. Here's what I tried so far:

```
        let path = "~/Downloads/Game_Folder/GameFile.obb"
        let hasFile = FileManager().fileExists(atPath: path)
        if hasFile {
            installationLabel.stringValue = "Game Files Found!"
        }
        else {
            installationLabel.stringValue = "Game Files Not Found"
        }
```

It will always say "Game files not found" when testing. I haven't found a definitive solution for this in Swift 5 yet, so that's why I'm asking.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is not the correct way to access the Downloads folder. Remember, you are sandboxed, plus the "twiddle" character means nothing to the File Manager.

Comment: How would I access the Downloads folder then? I have enabled Read/Write for the Downloads folder in "Signing and Capabilities" so I should have permission right?

Comment: You have to ask the File Manager where the Downloads folder is, and go from there. For example see https://stackoverflow.com/q/50200377/341994

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a file exists in the Documents directory in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181699/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-the-documents-directory-in-swift)

Comment: Technically yes, but I figured out a way more elegant solution I believe. I posted it beneath the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's what I put for Swift 5.

```
let path = NSString(string: "~/test-node.js").expandingTildeInPath
let fileDoesExist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
```

The "~/test-node.js" should be replaced with the path of the file you want to verify exists.