# Cocoa: Capture Screen and scale image on saving in Swift

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift5

Below code I am using to capture screen in macOS application,

```
let img = CGDisplayCreateImage(CGMainDisplayID())

guard let destination = FileManager.default.urls(for: .downloadsDirectory,
    in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent("shot.jpg", isDirectory: false)
else {
    print("Unable to save captured image!")
    return
}
            
let properties: CFDictionary = [
    kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth: "900",
    kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight: "380"
] as CFDictionary
            
if let dest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(destination as CFURL, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, properties) {
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(dest, img!, properties)
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(dest)
}
else {
    print("Unable to create captured image to the destination!")
}
```

I have to scale the image to particular size while saving. So, I used `CFDictionary` with `width, heigh` properties of the image. But It's seems I am doing it as wrong. Please help me to find out correct solution. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: `NSImge` `draw(in:from:operation:fraction:)`

Comment: @ElTomato If I convert CGImage to NSImage then the JPEG representation of the NSImage capacity will higher than the original un scaled image capacity on storage. That's the problem.

Comment: "It's seems I am doing it as wrong" doesn't really describe the issue you face.  If you don't want to resize the image, then what is the issue that you are addressing?

Comment: @ElTomato, I am look for the solution to resize the image while saving it from CGImage by setting the `properties` or any other way. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/cgimageproperties/individual_image_properties

Comment: Again, "It's seems I am doing it as wrong" doesn't really describe the issue you face.

Comment: @ElTomato, Please see the answer. That's what I needed. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't resize using `CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL` or `CGImageDestinationAddImage`. If you look at the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/1465361-cgimagedestinationcreatewithurl) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/1464962-cgimagedestinationaddimage) you will notice that neither `kCGImagePropertyPixelWidth` or `kCGImagePropertyPixelHeight` is supported.

You will need to resize manually. You can use this tool, or modify it, if you find it helpful. It supports fill (stretch) and fit (scale while keeping the original aspect ratio) content modes. If you specify `.fit` it will center the drawing in the resulting image. If you specify `.fill` it will fill the whole space stretching whichever dimension it needs to.

```
enum ImageResizer {

    enum ContentMode {
        case fill
        case fit
    }

    enum Error: Swift.Error {
        case badOriginal
        case resizeFailed
    }

    static func resize(_ source: CGImage, to targetSize: CGSize, mode: ContentMode) throws -> CGImage {

        let context = CGContext(
            data: nil,
            width: Int(targetSize.width),
            height: Int(targetSize.height),
            bitsPerComponent: source.bitsPerComponent,
            bytesPerRow: 0,
            space: source.colorSpace ?? CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
            bitmapInfo: source.bitmapInfo.rawValue
        )

        guard let context = context else {
            throw Error.badOriginal
        }

        let drawingSize: CGSize
        switch mode {
        case .fill:
            drawingSize = targetSize
        case .fit:
            drawingSize = CGSize(width: source.width, height: source.height)
                .scaledToFit(target: targetSize)
        }

        let drawRect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize)
            .makeCenteredRect(withSize: drawingSize)

        context.interpolationQuality = .high
        context.draw(source, in: drawRect)

        guard let result = context.makeImage() else {
            throw Error.resizeFailed
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

`ImageResizer` depends on these CG extensions for scaling the source image and centering scaled image:

```
extension CGSize {

    var maxDimension: CGFloat {
        Swift.max(width, height)
    }

    var minDimension: CGFloat {
        Swift.min(width, height)
    }

    func scaled(by scalar: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(width: width * scalar, height: height * scalar)
    }

    func scaleFactors(to target: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        CGSize(
            width: target.width / width,
            height: target.height / height
        )
    }

    func scaledToFit(target: CGSize) -> CGSize {
        return scaled(by: scaleFactors(to: target).minDimension)
    }
}

extension CGRect {
    func makeCenteredRect(withSize size: CGSize) -> CGRect {
        let origin = CGPoint(
            x: midX - size.width / 2.0,
            y: midY - size.height / 2.0
        )
        return CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)
    }
}
```

Also, make sure you set up [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50200377/how-to-create-a-directory-in-downloads-folder-with-swift-on-macos-permission-ex) if you're going to save to `.downloadsDirectory`.